# What determines the secondary gun I get from buddy rescue?

Tags: far-cry-2

When being rescued by your buddy in a danger zone, your buddy will eventually hand you a secondary gun (pistol) that is not your own. I've noticed however that in Act 1 I get a rusted [Star .45](http://farcry.wikia.com/wiki/Star_.45), whereas in Act 2 I've been getting a shiny [Eagle .50](http://farcry.wikia.com/wiki/Eagle_.50).

So what determines the gun that will be handed to me? Does it have anything to do with the act of the game, or the buddy, or any guns I've purchased?